# Bot famework composer - Dependency injection in Custom Action

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, botframework

I am referring to this article for running a long running task in background while returning 200 response immediately in bot framework composer.
https://github.com/EricDahlvang/ImmediateAcceptAdapter

Here, instead of Thread.Sleep in Custom Action, I have to make an http call which sometimes takes more than 15 secs.
I need some help in injecting a service with http call in the Sleep Custom Action.

Comment: Can't you just replace the `thread.sleep` line with the code you have to make the http call? Do you have the call working already in a non-bot .NET application?

Comment: Please add any code that you have attempted to get to work or errors.